# Firebase: The continue URL provided in the request is invalid. (auth/invalid-continue-uri)

Tags: firebase, react-native

I have a resetPassword method which displays the error message

> Firebase: The continue URL provided in the request is invalid. (auth/invalid-continue-uri).
> I cannot seem to find any related problems on this and none of the tutorials / docs mention a continue-url (I am making a mobile application with react native so adding a url is confusing me). Also my console.log("reset email sent to " + email); shows the correct email address but the email never comes through. Any help is appreciated.

My code:
`

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { View, TextInput, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableWithoutFeedback, Keyboard, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import { auth } from '../firebase';

const ForgotPasswordScreen = () => {

    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');

    const resetPassword = () => {

      console.log("reset email sent to " + email);
      auth
      .sendPasswordResetEmail(auth, email)
          .then(() => {
              alert("reset email sent to " + email);
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
              console.log(error);
          });
  };

  return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => {
        Keyboard.dismiss();
      }}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={styles.heading}>Forgot your password?</Text>
          <Text style={styles.heading}>Enter your email address and we will send you a link to reset your password!</Text>
            <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
            <TextInput placeholder='Email'
              placeholderTextColor="black"
              keyboardType='email-address'
              value={email}
              onChangeText={text => setEmail(text)} style={styles.input} />
            </View>

            <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={resetPassword} style={styles.button} >
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Send Reset Link To Email</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  )
}

export default ForgotPasswordScreen
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by changing `.sendPasswordResetEmail(auth, email)` to `.sendPasswordResetEmail(email)`